# Blazor & IndexedDb: poor performance

Tags: javascript, json, blazor, indexeddb

I'm setting up a Blazor Service to interact with the browser IndexedDb via javascript. However I have very poor performances when dealing with quite large JSON files (arrays of around 3000 "activities": [details](https://data.destinysets.com/api/Destiny2.GetActivityHistory?characterId=2305843009403261815&destinyMembershipId=4611686018476641937&membershipType=3&count=250&mode=5&page=0)). There are two factors:

1. Transferring large strings (json) between blazor and javascript. I've seen some ways to improve this using byte arrays to transfer data but I'm not sure it's enough. Currently the transfer takes around 7s.
2. Parsing JSON with Newtonsoft.JsonConvert is very slow compare to javascript (<1s for JS compare to 40s to Blazor). So having to convert the data into JSON to put it into IndexedDb is not optimal when I want to retreive the data.

Are there some ways to improve the performances? Or other alternatives to store data permanently in the browser more effectively with Blazor than IndexedDB?

Comment: Did you enable AoT when publishing?

Comment: No I'll try with it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using smaller objects? For example, store the activities as separate objects instead of within one large object.

Storing large arrays in a single object is generally an anti-pattern that is best avoided when working with a no-sql database.

Comment: yes, actually for the first point, using marshal types helps a lot in transfer times. For the serialization issue, it is apparently an issue from blazor WASM: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40386